# The order topology of a subset is the restriction of the order topology of the total?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,<_X)$ a linear ordered set. Let $T_{<_X}$ the order topology in $X$ generated by the subbase:
$$\mathcal S=\{\{x\in X\mid a<_Xx\}\mid a\in X\}\cup\{\{x\in X\mid x<_Xb\}\mid b\in X\}$$

Let $E\subset X$ and $(E,<_E)$ with $<_E$ the linear order of $E$ inherited from $X$ $(<_X\mid_E=<_E)$.

Then, the order topology in $E$, $T_{<_E}$, is the restriction to $E$ of the order topology of the $X$, $T_{<_X}\mid_E$? $$(T_{<_X}\mid_E\overset{?}{=}T_{<_E})$$

**My attempt**

My first thought was that this must be false. I was working in a counterexample using $(\mathbb R, <_\mathbb R)$ with $<_\mathbb R$ the usual order in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb N\subset \mathbb R$ with $<_\mathbb N$ the usual order in $\mathbb N$ and $<_\mathbb R\mid_\mathbb N=<_\mathbb N$, because $T_{<_\mathbb R}\mid_\mathbb N$ is the discert topology.  But then I wonder $T_{<_\mathbb N}$ is also the discret topology. I conclude that I am going to have the same problem if $E$ is a subset of isolated points of $X$. Then I have been thinking about $\mathbb Q$. Here $T_{<_\mathbb Q}$ is not the discrete topology but I belive that also coincide.

I alredy belive that the equality doesn't holds, because I can't think in a proof of that. But I still can't find some counterexample. If you could guide me, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. The subspace topology of the order topology of the superset coincide with the order topology of the subset if the subset is convex in the order. Otherwise pick the following counterexample:

$(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{order})$ and the subspace topology of $A:=[0,1) \cup \{2\}$. You see $A$ is not convex in the order and so the subspace topology inherited by the order topology of the real line and the order topology on $A$ are different.

Comment: why they are different?

Comment: I fixed the example. Now the topologies *are* different.

Comment: @GoRza because $1-\frac1n \to 2$ in the order topology on $A$ but not in the subspace topology.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Henno!

Comment: @GoRza, how are open sets defined in the subspace topology and in the order topology? What can you say about the set $\{2\}$ in each of them?

Comment: Now I understand the counterexample: $(1,\rightarrow)\cap A=\{2\}$so $\{2\}$ is open in the subspace but in the order topology the memebers of the subbase that include $\{2\}$ $(x,1)\cup\{2\}$ with $0\leq x<1$. So the member of the basis that include $\{2\}$ are the same. So every neighbourhood of $2$ include points in $(0,1)$ , therefore $\{2\}$ is not open here.

Comment: Exactly as that :)